# Need to add a constant value in a column while loading a hive table

Tags: hive

I created a table named table1 in hive and i need to insert data from table2 into table1. I used the below statemnt to get the output. 
Also i need to add a new column  with some constant value -- colx = 'colval' along with the columns in table2 but am not sure how to add it.. Thanks!

INSERT INTO TABLE table1 select * FROM table2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to drop `table1` and recreate it from scratch, you could do this:

```
-- I'm using Hive 0.13.0
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT *, 'colval' AS colx FROM TABLE2;
```

If that is not an option for some reason, you can use `INSERT OVERWRITE`:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMNS (colx STRING); -- Assuming you haven't created the column already
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table1 SELECT *, 'colval' FROM table2;
```